# Get the aspx files collection from my project

Tags: c#

How can I read all my aspx file names that I have into my project? I need to get the collection of my aspx files.

I want to add them into a `DropDownList`.

Like

```
foreach(ASPX file in myProject.aspx.collections) {
  dropdownlist1.Items.Add(file.name);//Name could be: Default.aspx
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Thank you friends, really all your answers were correct. Finally I did it as next:

```
string sourceDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/");
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
var aspxFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.aspx", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(Path.GetFileName);

foreach (string currentFile in aspxFiles) {
    this.dropdownlist1.Items.Add(currentFile);
}
```

Comment: With reflection, what have you tried?

Comment: FileNames like: Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the files in the same way you'd read any files from a folder.

Just you need to 'convert' the virtual folder reference to a physical one:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1273264.aspx/1

Then you can just use Directory.EnumerateFiles() with the aspx filter to get all files.

Comment: That's a simple and good idea, I tried converting from virtual folder to physical and using Directory.EnumerateFiles() and also using Directory.GetFiles(); in both cases I'm getting full file info like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectfolder\Default.aspx. But I'm just interested in getting only the name (Default.aspx). Anyway thank u Haedrian.

Comment: @Poyson1: If you want only the filename, use `Path.GetFilename(fullPath)`.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance my friend, just had to add the method Select(Path.GetFileName) after Directory.EnumerateFiles().

Answer (score 3):

With reflection, this should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> getAspxNames()
{
    var pageTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Page));
    return pageTypes.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();
}

// ...
foreach(string pageName in getAspxNames())
    dropdownlist1.Items.Add(pageName + ".aspx");
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I tested your snippet but I dont know why I'm just getting 3 files names from my project, and I have 7 Pages (aspx files) into it...

Comment: @Poyson1: I don't know why you miss 4 page types. Are you sure that these types are declared in this assembly and that they don't inherit from each other(what might be a problem in the code above), so that they actually inherit from `Page` directly(e.g. no master-page, ashx or usercontrol)?

Comment: No, It's a simple project with one master-page and 7 aspx, anyway I solved it as I described above. Many thanks my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var dirPath = Server.MapPath("~/");
var ext = new List<string> {".aspx"};
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)
     .Where(s => ext.Any(ex => s.EndsWith(ex));

dropdownlist1.DataSource = fileList;
dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

For only file names do this

```
foreach(string file in fileList)
 dropdownlist1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Comment: Hi rs. Thank you for your answer but if I use this snippet I'll get the full file infor as I said before (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectfolder\Default.aspx.) and I'm just needing the name (default.aspx)